# TypeScript: .mts file extension does not work as expected (tsc emits commonJS code instead)

Tags: typescript

[This page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/esm-node.html) says:

> In turn, TypeScript supports two new source file extensions: **.mts** and **.cts**. When TypeScript emits these to JavaScript files, it will emit them to **.mjs** and **.cjs** respectively.

(emphasis mine)

I'm aware that it *only* says that it'll emit `.mts` files to `.mjs` files but I do expect that it will adhere to the module system chosen by the file extension.

What do I mean?

When I setup a blank project with `npm install --save-dev typescript` and a single file `example.mts` with the following contents:

```js
import path from "path"

console.log(
    path.resolve("./")
)
```

I expect that `./node_modules/.bin/tsc example.mts` results in (at the **very** least) a file created `example.mjs` with the following contents:

```js
import path from "path"

console.log(
    path.resolve("./")
)
```

But instead, `tsc` decides to output:

```js
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var path_1 = require("path");
console.log(path_1["default"].resolve("./"));
```

Why is that?

Edit: filed a [bug report](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51990) on github.

Comment: You are correct. I have not found a combination of compiler options that allows you to preserve an `.mts` file as an ES module if you want to compile your other `.ts` files to CJS, i.e. `--module commonjs`. Anytime you use `--module commonjs` your `.mts` file will emit as an `.mjs` extension but use the CJS module system, i.e. `require`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is that?

I don't really have a technical answer for you without digging through the source code on the TS repo. I prefer good old vanilla ECMAScript to TypeScript, so I'm not super interested in doing that. I do have some experience working with `tsc` and this particular problem, however. I can confirm your findings.

It seems that no matter what combination of `--moduleResolution` or other options you throw at it, anytime you use `--module commonjs` the `tsc` compiler will convert your `.mts` file to one with an `.mjs` extension, *but using the CommonJS module system!* This occurs whether your package.json uses `"type": "module"`, or not.

You can [read more about it](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51990#issuecomment-1656904811) on your bug report.

This clearly violates the [TypeScript design goals](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals) #4 and #7. You can see an example of how the emitted `.mjs` does not work with Node.js under either module system in this [PR comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/50985#issuecomment-1656991606).

You can use `—-module nodenext` to preserve the `.mts` module system, and other `.ts` files in the project will compile to the `type` defined in your package.json file. Unfortunately this creates extra bloat if you want to create a [dual package](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#dual-commonjses-module-packages) with only one package.json and tsconfig.json.